# Where do questions that ask for programming technology solutions belong?

Tags: discussion, scope

For example, this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482993/chat-server-design-without-using-a-database-or-kafka

In reference to the guidelines of SO, asking what technology solution to use is not:

- a specific programming problem
- a software algorithm

But, in reference to the guidelines of SO it does ask about:

- software tools commonly used by programmers
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

I ask because I've seen many questions like the one posted above flagged and then closed as "off-topic". It's interesting because I definitely see how questions like these don't really fit into the great niche that SO has become, which strictly *seems* to be about asking a specific technical answer and getting a specific technical solution; a solution that may vary from author to author but are unbiased/objective in nature.

Questions like the one above seem to be open to opinions which can lead into long, broad answers. In otherwords, while the question may not be literally "off-topic" by SO standards, the answers are at risk of being genuinely off-topic. But the question itself does seem to have a place in SO if presented appropriately, but that's the tricky part.

Where do questions like those belong? One might think **SE: Programming**, but they get shut down there, too. Thoughts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic does pretty much list what OTHER things are off-topic... and "off-site resources" fall under there..

Comment: @Patrice "Where do questions like those belong?"

Comment: I was answering your title ;) "Are questions that ask for technology solutions off-topic in SO?"

Comment: @Patrice Fair enough :] Wasn't trying to pull a "gotcha" moment, sorry haha. I guess I should maybe change my question.

Comment: honestly, I don't know if this is on topic for any place of the network. If asking for specific tools/libraries/clients, then MAYBE software recommendations (read their guidelines, I'm not super familiar with them)

Comment: Search engines are designed to index web pages as quickly as possible, and keep these indexes as up to date as possible.  Therefore, when choosing between a search engine and a question on Stack Overflow asked four years ago when searching for tools, it's generally better to go with the search engine.  Also, while I might recommend you use a product like, for example, the Entity Framework, you must understand that I'm a tricksy asshole.  It is always better that you, the ultimate consumer, prototype the latest tools found on search engines to determine which is best for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Where do questions like those belong? One might think **SE: Programming**, but they get shut down there, too. Thoughts?

They belong to the [limbo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278023/question-stuck-in-intersite-limbo) for nearly much every SE site. The primary reasons to close listed below will apply for all sites:

Well, let's dissect that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482993/chat-server-design-without-using-a-database-or-kafka) in question you're mentioning:

> > This is a design question I came across, I've searched on the net and on stackoverflow but haven't found something that answers this use case.

No mention of what research was done in particular, or how.

> > The question is to design a simple chat server that can serve multiple clients (one chat room, message is broadcast to all connected clients, no authentication to connect).

There are tons of examples for such applications to be found by simply googling.

> > When a new client joins (or when an old client reconnects), the client is shown the last 10 messages. However, the chat server needs to be designed without using a database or message queue. Any language or platform can be used to implement this.

The simple answer is that server needs to keep that in memory (RAM).

> > Can you help point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Asking for third party resources is off-topic.

---

#### TL;DR;

VTC as *too broad*, *asking 4 3rd party resource*, *opinion based* whatever. Downvote as *not useful*.

Comment: Thank you; great answer. As in FYI, because I can't tell by your choice of wording, I didn't write that particular question.

Comment: @8protons I understood it wasn't _your_ question. Hope that wording satisfies you more now.